# Stopping Time for a sequence of Random Variables

Tags: random-variable, stochastic-processes, stopping-time

If $M$ and $N$ are stopping times of sequence $\{X_n\}$ where $n \geq 1$. Then are $min (M, N)$ and $max(M,N)$ also stopping times of the sequence $\{X_n\}$ ?

Is there any rigorous way to prove whether or not $min (M, N)$ and $max(M,N)$ are stopping times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stopping time $T$ for a sequence $\{X_n\}$ is a measurable random variable for which the event
$$
\{ \omega : T(\omega) \leq n \}
$$

is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable where

$$
\mathcal F_n = \sigma \left(X_1,\dots,X_n \right)
$$
If $M$ and $N$ are stopping times for $\{X_n \}$ then for $n \geq 0$, ($\wedge$ = min, $\vee$ = max):
\begin{align*}
\left \{ \omega : M (\omega) \wedge N (\omega) \leq n \right \} &= \underbrace{\left \{ \omega : M (\omega)  \leq n \right \} }_{\in \mathcal F_n}\cup \underbrace{\left \{ \omega : N (\omega)  \leq n \right \} }_{\in \mathcal F_n}
\end{align*}

Since $\mathcal F_n$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, is it stable by countable unions and
$\left \{ \omega : M (\omega) \wedge N (\omega) \leq n \right \} \in \mathcal F_n$ hence $M \wedge N$ is a stopping time.

In the same way we have,

\begin{align*}
\left \{ \omega : M (\omega) \vee N (\omega) \leq n \right \} &= \left \{ \omega : M (\omega)  \leq n \right \} \cap\left \{ \omega : N (\omega)  \leq n \right \}  \\
&\in \mathcal F_n
\end{align*}
and $M \vee N$ is also a stopping time.